# Data bound to ng-grid is not shown

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

Why is the data "myOptions" bound to the ng-grid not shown at all?

I see no errors in my browser console.

http://plnkr.co/edit/0DJ6W7QEPx2UzpdzDrVu?p=info

```
'use strict';
angular.module('projectplanner').controller('ProjectsController', function($scope, $state) {

  alert('shit');
  $scope.myData = [{
    name: "business refactor",
    projectId: 50
  }, {
    name: "Titanum restructure",
    projectId: 43
  }, {
    name: "Outsource development",
    projectId: 27
  }];

  $scope.myOptions = {
    data: 'myData',
    multiSelect: false,
    selectedItems: [],
    afterSelectionChange: function(rowItem) {
      if (rowItem.selected) {
        $state.go('projects.selected', {
          projectId: rowItem.entity.projectId
        });
      }
    }
  };

});



<div ng-grid="myOptions"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you forgot to include `ngGrid` in your application.

```
angular.module('projectplanner', ['ui.router', 'ngGrid'])
```

See this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/hk7hFxkMWqb4JcUm2Eam?p=preview)